# Do you need to deregister scope watches when scope is destroyed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Let's say you create a local scope and then call `$scope.$watch()` or `$scope.$on()`. When the local scope is destroyed, do you need to deregister each by calling the deregistration method returned from the call to `$watch` or `$on` or will they automatically be registered?

I'm trying to clean up some memory leaks and this looks like it could potentially be one. And of course the documentation isn't real clear on this.

Answer (score 0):

Watchers and listeners will automatically be cleaned up. Both are saved as properties of the scope they are registered on: [watchers](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/rootScope.js#L350) in `$$watchers` and [listeners](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/rootScope.js#L1015) in `$$listeners`.